# histroy.back() to latest URL without hash

Tags: javascript, navigation, history

In my gallery I set the hash into the URL for every different Image which is displayed, so I can navigate to this directly via URL later.

But the problem is: If the user navigates back, he will get through every image he viewed. I want to navigate back to "real" URL without the hash. Is this possible?

**Referrer**

```
http://mydomain.de/othersite
```

**Current URL**

```
http://mydomain.de/gallery#image-5
```

I want to navigate to back to referrer via

```
history.back()
```

or something like this.